# How to create List within a Textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, html, list, textarea

How can implement a list within a Textarea. Where User click in text area it should generate 1st listitem no and also same when pressing Enter key.

Comment: You didn't even specify a language

Comment: html, Javascript, Jquery, PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put it inside a textarea what you can do is make a DIV editable and use HTML inside and style it to look like a textarea,

This piece of code is exactly what you want and when user press enter it will generate.

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
<ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is, let the user write all the data in the text file, where each data goes in the next line.Use ***php*** in the action page to ***get*** the data and then explode it using [***explode()***](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) to get individual list element in an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't apply any html tag inside textarea.

Probably you should use and editor for this.

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/